# Displaying a working hyperlink on XML using only CSS

Tags: html, css, xml, hyperlink, xlink

Our assignment was to display an xml document using css, and that we need to have a hyperlink that would direct to a certain webpage. We can't make the text into a hyperlink using only css, we've searched a lot and couldn't find a way to do it. We tried using xlink and still not working.

Heres our test code for xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Test1.css"?>

  <topfive xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Top Movie</title>
    <span></span>
    <intro>Following are my favorite movie:</intro>
 
    <item>
     1. <itemLink xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="new"
     xlink:actuate="onRequest"
     xlink:href="http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B00004TDTO/">
     Jaws</itemLink>
   </item>
   </topfive>
```

and heres the css:

```
topfive {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

item {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
span:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```